# How to consume a WCF webservice from xamarin android using PCL

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I am calling wcf webservice for xamarin android project by creating a PCL to access service. I googled about this and found no clear solution to call wcf services in xamarin.

I have followed this link http://eidand.com/2015/07/25/xamarin-rest-services-pcl/ and did a sample on this but enable to get response and tells me that this expression is not supported with no error and status-code 200

Can anybody help me through this,I have already posted question regarding this,I am unable to get any suggestion or answer and started to rip my hairoff.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  Someone posted a very useful comment on your earlier question: have you read it?

Comment: Did you try this link? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

Comment: @xleon i have referred this but find no clear example on how to implement.